# ClassNotFoundException com.sun.mail.util.SharedByteArrayInputStream

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am getting the following error when my deployed system sends an email.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/mail/util/SharedByteArrayInputStream
....
....
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.mail.util.SharedByteArrayInputStream
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass
```

I am using:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
   <version>1.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

This has been working for the past year and now suddenly it is throwing this exception. I have changed any of the versions of `javax.mail` etc.

I tried adding `javax.mail:mail:jar:1.5.0` to the dependencies but when compiling I got an error saying that that jar was illegal. Maven gives the following error: `Please use the correct artifact for JavaMail. You should be using com.sun.mail:javax.mail...` & `Found Banned Dependency: javax.mail:mail:jar:1.5.0`

What seems odd to me is that `javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage` has the following imports:

```
import com.sun.mail.util.*;
import javax.mail.util.SharedByteArrayInputStream;
```

So it seems odd that I get this error when creating a `MimeMessage` in that it is trying to get `com.sun.mail.util.SharedByteArrayInputStream` instead of `javax.mail.util.SharedByteArrayInputStream`.

I know similar questions have been posted but the answers always seem to be to use `javax.mail.jar` which I am already using.

Comment: Is javax.mail.jar being packaged in your web application?  Is there another jar file with javax.mail classes somewhere in your classpath, perhaps somewhere in the lib directory of your server?

Comment: @BillShannon It is. Any idea what other libs to look for. Is there any clue in that it is looking for the ```com.sun.mail.util``` version instead of the ```javax.mail.util``` version?

Comment: I checked my tomcat instance and the only mail jars I find are ```javax.mail-1.5.1.jar``` and ```bcmail-jdk15on-1.50.jar```

Comment: It sounds like you have a very old version of the javax.mail classes on your classpath somewhere.  Are you sure there isn't a j2ee.jar or javaee.jar in there somewhere?  Look inside all the jar files for javax.mail classes.

Comment: @BillShannon you ROCK! Thank you. The ```j2ee.jar``` had been added incorrectly. If you post an answer I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you have a very old version of the javax.mail classes on your classpath somewhere. Are you sure there isn't a j2ee.jar or javaee.jar in there somewhere? Look inside all the jar files for javax.mail classes.

Comment: I have j2ee-1.0 which I am not able to remove. Is there any way to enforce or override to use javax

Comment: Put the JavaMail jar file earlier in your classpath.  Are you deploying your application to an application server?

Comment: Yes tomcat server

Comment: I believe you should be able to put the JavaMail jar file in Tomcat's lib directory.

Comment: added javax. mail/ mail1.4.4  in first place in pom. tried adding it in tomcat lib. still the same error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/mail/util/SharedByteArrayInputStream

Answer (score 0):

To solve it, you need to include the mail.jar as well, which you can get it from your JavaEE SDK folder or JavaMail API official page.

Again, to send Email via JavaMail API, you need to include both javaee.jar and mail.jar libraries.

http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/javax/mail/mail/1.4.1/mail-1.4.1.jar

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html

Comment: When I try to include this (```javax.mail / mail / 1.5.0```) Maven gives the following error: ```Please use the correct artifact for JavaMail. You should be using com.sun.mail:javax.mail...``` & ```Found Banned Dependency: javax.mail:mail:jar:1.5.0```

Comment: javaee.jar should never be included in your runtime; it's only intended for compiling against.