# Why is 'boolean com.sun.mail.util.PropUtil.getBooleanSessionProperty(javax.mail.Session, java.lang.String, boolean)' not found?

Tags: java, spring-boot, email, mime-message

I'd like to write some tests for particuar classes. Yet, I want to read in an EML file. This works fine by using

```
IOUtils.toString(r.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

I have a class which is (normally) able to read such an EML (by InputStream, filename or file content(String)) what is done so far in multiple places in the project. When I try to do this in a test class I get this:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean com.sun.mail.util.PropUtil.getBooleanSessionProperty(javax.mail.Session, java.lang.String, boolean)'

    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.initStrict(MimeMessage.java:320)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.<init>(MimeMessage.java:215)
    at d.d.a.c.e.EmlFileHolder.buildByEmlFile(EmlFileHolder.java:103)
    at d.d.a.c.e.EmlFileHolder.buildByEmlFileStream(EmlFileHolder.java:99)
    at d.d.a.c.e.EmlFileHolder.buildByEmlFileString(EmlFileHolder.java:81)
```

Maybe a problem with the dependencies? (But I couldn't solve or even figure out the problem.) Here, the imported dependencies related to mail, MimeMessages, ...

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.mail-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.mail</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.simplejavamail</groupId>
    <artifactId>simple-java-mail</artifactId>
    <version>${simple-java-mail.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.simplejavamail</groupId>
    <artifactId>smime-module</artifactId>
    <version>${simple-java-mail.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Did you fix it?

Comment: Why `jakarta.mail` instead of `javax.mail` ?

Comment: Compare with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44739269/classnotfoundexception-com-sun-mail-util-sharedbytearrayinputstream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be mixing code that uses the old `javax.mail.*` APIs (and thus `com.sun.mail.*`)  with the new `jakarta.mail` 2.0 API and implementation.

I suspect you managed this by updating to `jakarta.mail` in the POM but keeping `${simple-java-mail.version}` at 6.7.x or earlier.  (This is an inference.  It is not clear from your question what version you are actually using.)

If you are going to use `jakarta.mail` 2.0 and later, you need to use `simple-java-mail` 7.0 or later.

Alternatively, you could wind back to an earlier version of `javax.mail`.  (There are `jakarta.mail` 1.6.7 artifacts in Maven Central, but the are apparently just the corresponding `javax.mail` artifacts renamed.)

Comment: Yes, I tried to move from migrate to jakarte.. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.mail/javax.mail